# Exception : java.lang.RuntimeException at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver

Tags: java, android, notifications, media-player

i have an app published in Google play,and i'm stucking with below crash report in Google Console, can anyone help me to understand where this issue came from and how to get resolved.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3523)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:207)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1759)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6863)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:537)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>             at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver.onReceive
>   (MediaButtonReceiver.java:124)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3507)

**Notification** :

```
void startNotify(Context context, String playbackStatus, String title) {
        String titlesonge;
        String artist;
        try {
            titlesonge = StringUtils.substringBefore(title, " - ");
            artist = StringUtils.substringAfter(title, " - ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            titlesonge = title.substring(0, title.indexOf(" - "));
            artist = title.substring(title.lastIndexOf(" - ") - 1);
        }
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_pause_white;
        Intent playbackAction = new Intent(service, RadioService.class);
        playbackAction.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_PAUSE);
        PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 1, playbackAction, 0);
        if (playbackStatus.equals(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED)) {
            icon = R.drawable.ic_play_white;
            playbackAction.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_PLAY);
            action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 2, playbackAction, 0);

        }
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(service, RadioService.class);
        stopIntent.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_STOP);
        PendingIntent stopAction = PendingIntent.getService(service, 3, stopIntent, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(service, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(service, 0, intent, 0);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        String PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME = "PRIMARY";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentTitle(titlesonge)
                .setContentText(artist)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.largeicon))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallwidth)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorneeded))
                .addAction(icon, "pause", action)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop_white, "stop", stopAction)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(service.getMediaSession().getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1)
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(stopAction));
        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve in 3 steps.
1:_ Open your build.gradle(Module: app) file.
Add this under the application tag

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2:_ If you using appcompact then add this line under the dependencies tag

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

else if you migrate your project to AndroidX then add this line

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

3:_ Open your all activity java files and add MultiDex.intall(contextName)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
MultiDex.install(this);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);
        `enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add flag to your PendingIntent for Android 12 and above.
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12)